# three.js : Is there a better way to select individual UV's from a texture to display on a sprite?

Tags: javascript, three.js, sprite, texture-mapping

I have a texture sheet with various game HUD elements UV packed into the texture.

For every single part of the GUI, I'm having to create a clone() of the texture I loaded (yes, I know it's a shallow copy). And then create a material using this texture. This is so I can use different UV's for the component parts of the
HUD elements.

Is there a better way of doing this? It seems very slow and cumbersome.

The way I did it on Android/iOS/Blackberry was with a GLES VertexBuffer. Just adding vertices and rebuilding on the fly, as the HUD/GUI elements may change / be removed at any time.

Here's a screenie what I'm trying to achieve. The menu option boxes are made up of 4 corners, 4 sides and a centre. This allows me to adjust the display to the resolution without losing texture resolution.

[image: Android screenie]

Comment: Are you 100% sure it's a shallow copy? I've been having some conflicting results, and unable to run webgl inspector to confirm.

Comment: I'm going on the Texture docs on the main site here: https://threejs.org/docs/#api/textures/Texture

Which states :
".clone ( texture )
Make copy of the texture. Note this is not a "deep copy", the image is shared."

Answer (score 0):

Rather than transforming the textures, you can transform the UVs of the mesh you are using.

Using `PlaneGeometry` rather than `PlaneBufferGeometry` here would be slightly easier. For each element you would scale the uvs and translate them to match the atlas. This can further be optimized by merging all the geometry into one, or by using instancing and some GLSL.

Comment: Hi there (I've updated the original question for clarity)

I'm not using a mesh, I'm using three.js Sprites and an ortho view. Are you saying programatically create a mesh of the whole GUI? 

Looks like BufferGeometry may be what I'm looking for.

Thanks.

Comment: It pretty much depends on your use case. How many elements you have etc. Drawcalls have a lot of overhead so it may not be the most optimal to draw each element on their own. Instead of glPoints (Sprites) you can use a quad mesh. Sprites do not have uvs, nor i think they can be scaled, because they're not meshes. You can control them with uniforms though, take the greater of width/height use that for gl_PointSize, and scale/clip the other axis in the fragment shader.